# customer address is not stored in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, forms, customer-address, registration

I am using this code but value is not stored in Magento2

```
<div class="field telephone required">
                <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'phoneUS':true}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address') ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please select a region, state or province.') ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my comment and let me know still your question not solve. If it will helpful for you then accept and upvote answer. So,other user can use this answer.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has missing this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
```

Comment: after phone code I use this line?

Comment: yes you can put before telephone filed